# Hmailserver database version could not be detected

Tags: mysql, xampp, hmail-server

Okay so I'm trying to install HMailServer on my Windows 7 PC with XAMPP, and connect it to the MySQL database in XAMPP. I've been Googling for hours and only finding either ineffective or invalid answers.

I went through the installation to the database set up and selected:

- Select a new Hmail server default database
- MySQL
- Database Server address: E6400, port 3306, Database name: Douglas (All correct I checked it out in PHPmyadmin) Then I typed in my Username and password for a user that I granted all privileges too on the database...
- Left service dependency blank
- Then on the finish screen it returned

  ```
  Starting task...
  Please wait while updating database settings...
  Settings updated.
  Restarting server...
  Database version could not be detected.
  ```

I did place a libmysql.dll file in the hmail server bin (not one from XAMPP because I couldn't find one in there).

Here's my error logs:

```
    "ERROR" 5460    "2015-06-26 21:34:37.341"   "Severity: 2 (High), Code: HM5033, Source: DALRecordset::Open, Description: MySQL: Table 'email.hm_dbversion' doesn't exist (Additional info: select * from hm_dbversion)"
    "ERROR" 5460    "2015-06-26 21:34:37.341"   "Severity: 1 (Critical), Code: HM5010, Source: Application::OnDatabaseConnected, Description: Database version could not be detected."
```

Do I need to manually create the table .hm_dbversion or something? Let me know if I need to include more information. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into this same issue. This is how I resolved it. There may be a better method to do this but this is what worked for me:

1. Run the installer and tell it you want to use a different database (MySQL).
2. Once the installer gets to the step where you setup the database, just cancel the database setup.
3. Open you hMail folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\DBScripts)
4. Locate the 'CreateTablesMYSQL.sql' file.
5. Use a MySQL database editor to create a new schema and execute the above sql file into that new schema.
6. Next, open the hMail database setup app. (C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\DBSetup.exe)
7. Go through the steps to setup your MySQL database using the new schema you just created as the database.
8. If all was done well, you should fly thr

Comment: I gave up on this a little while ago, thanks for rejuvenating my dreams lol. Million thanks atom0s!

Comment: Step 7: Ran CreateTablesMYSQL.sql under a new database that I created under phpmyadmin called mailserver on 64bit Windows 10 Home Edition, Wampserver 3.2.9 64bit and php 8.1.8. I named the hmailserver database text input 'mailserver'. This is the same name that I gave the database under which I ran the above sql file under phpmyadmin. The hmailserver domain I called 'localhost'. The setup software picked it up. Incidentally, I also downloaded the 32 bit version of libmysql.dll from https://www.dlldownloader.com/libmysql-dll/#google_vignette  . Essential!